# Spring Boot - inject map from application.yml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) application with the following `application.yml` - taken basically from [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-application-info):

```
info:
   build:
      artifact: ${project.artifactId}
      name: ${project.name}
      description: ${project.description}
      version: ${project.version}
```

I can inject particular values, e.g.

```
@Value("${info.build.artifact}") String value
```

I would like, however, to inject the whole map, i.e. something like this:

```
@Value("${info}") Map<String, Object> info
```

Is that (or something similar) possible? Obviously, I can load yaml directly, but was wondering if there's something already supported by Spring.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can have a map injected using `@ConfigurationProperties`:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class MapBindingSample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(SpringApplication.run(MapBindingSample.class, args)
                .getBean(Test.class).getInfo());
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties
    public Test test() {
        return new Test();
    }

    public static class Test {

        private Map<String, Object> info = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        public Map<String, Object> getInfo() {
            return this.info;
        }
    }
}
```

Running this with the yaml in the question produces:

```
{build={artifact=${project.artifactId}, version=${project.version}, name=${project.name}, description=${project.description}}}
```

There are various options for setting a prefix, controlling how missing properties are handled, etc. See the [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.4.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationProperties.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Andy - this works as expected. Interesting that it doesn't work without an extra class - i.e. you cannot put the `info` map within `MapBindingSample` for some reason (maybe because it's being used to run the app in `SpringApplication.run` call).

Comment: Is there a way to inject a sub-map? E.g. inject `info.build` instead of `info` from the above map?

Comment: Yes. Set the prefix on @ConfigurationProperties to info and then update Test replacing getInfo() with a method named getBuild()

Comment: Nice, thanks Andy, worked like a charm! One more thing - when setting `locations` (to get the properties from another `yml` file instead of the default `application.yml`) on `@ConfigurationProperties`, it worked, except it did not result in placeholders being replaced. E.g. if you had a system property `project.version=123` set, the example you gave in the answer would return `version=123`, while after setting `locations` it would return `project.version=${project.version}`. Do you know if there's a limitation of some sorts here?

Comment: That's a limitation. I've opened an issue (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1301) to perform placeholder replacement when you use a custom location

Comment: @AndyWilkinson How can I inject a map with type `Map<Enum,Class>`, because I want to have the map to record an Operation Type and the Handler(a class), how can I specify the type? Thank you!

Comment: I have a related problem, but slightly different. My applications.yml file contains something like this:
    foo: 
      bar: x
    sysprops:
    webdriver.chrome.driver: chromedriver
  
Unfortunately the YAML processor treats the dot separated key as nested. I've even tried 'webdriver.chrome.driver' but it doesn't make a difference. The result looks like this: webdriver: {chrome={driver=chromedriver}}
Is there an easy way to deal with this?

Comment: @user2337270 A new question would be a better place to ask

Comment: If you're trying to set the key for one of your values to a string with spaces, dots, or other special characters, try surrounding it with square brackets surrounded by quotes.  E.g. to "[key value.with.dots]"   to avoid having Spring strip those characters.

Comment: can we create a separate configuration class to create the bean, instead of writing it in main class?

Comment: @ajithgeorge Yes, you can.

Answer (score 124):

Below solution is a shorthand for @Andy Wilkinson's solution, except that it doesn't have to use a separate class or on a `@Bean` annotated method.

**application.yml:**

```
input:
  name: raja
  age: 12
  somedata:
    abcd: 1 
    bcbd: 2
    cdbd: 3
```

**SomeComponent.java:**

```
@Component
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "input")
class SomeComponent {

    @Value("${input.name}")
    private String name;

    @Value("${input.age}")
    private Integer age;

    private HashMap<String, Integer> somedata;

    public HashMap<String, Integer> getSomedata() {
        return somedata;
    }

    public void setSomedata(HashMap<String, Integer> somedata) {
        this.somedata = somedata;
    }

}
```

We can club both `@Value` annotation and `@ConfigurationProperties`, no issues. But getters and setters are important and `@EnableConfigurationProperties` is must to have the `@ConfigurationProperties` to work.

I tried this idea from groovy solution provided by @Szymon Stepniak, thought it will be useful for someone.

Comment: thanks!  I used spring boot 1.3.1 , in my case I found does not need `@EnableConfigurationProperties`

Comment: I get an 'invalid character constant' error when using this answer. Can you change:

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = 'input')

to use double quotes to prevent this error.

Comment: Good answer, but the @Value annotations are not necessary.

Comment: Instead of writing the dummy getter & setter you can use the Lombok annotations @Setter(AccessLevel.PUBLIC) and @Getter(AccessLevel.PUBLIC)

Comment: Genious. Note that configuration can also be nested: Map<String, Map<String, String>>

Comment: Do you think it's possible to build a tree-like structure with nodes each containing its own childrens?

Comment: Getter is not important here

Answer (score 35):

To retrieve map from configuration you will need configuration class. @Value annotation won't do the trick, unfortunately.

Application.yml

```
entries:
  map:
     key1: value1
     key2: value2
```

Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("entries")
@Getter
@Setter
 public static class MyConfig {
     private Map<String, String> map;
 }
```

Comment: tested the above solution works against version 2.1.0

Answer (score 18):

I run into the same problem today, but unfortunately Andy's solution didn't work for me. In Spring Boot 1.2.1.RELEASE it's even easier, but you have to be aware of a few things.

Here is the interesting part from my `application.yml`:

```
oauth:
  providers:
    google:
     api: org.scribe.builder.api.Google2Api
     key: api_key
     secret: api_secret
     callback: http://callback.your.host/oauth/google
```

`providers` map contains only one map entry, my goal is to provide dynamic configuration for other OAuth providers. I want to inject this map into a service that will initialize services based on the configuration provided in this yaml file. My initial implementation was:

```
@Service
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = 'oauth')
class OAuth2ProvidersService implements InitializingBean {

    private Map<String, Map<String, String>> providers = [:]

    @Override
    void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
       initialize()
    }

    private void initialize() {
       //....
    }
}
```

After starting the application, `providers` map in `OAuth2ProvidersService` was not initialized. I tried the solution suggested by Andy, but it didn't work as well. I use **Groovy** in that application, so I decided to remove `private` and let Groovy generates getter and setter. So my code looked like this:

```
@Service
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = 'oauth')
class OAuth2ProvidersService implements InitializingBean {

    Map<String, Map<String, String>> providers = [:]

    @Override
    void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
       initialize()
    }

    private void initialize() {
       //....
    }
}
```

After that small change everything worked.

Although there is one thing that might be worth mentioning. After I make it working I decided to make this field `private` and provide setter with straight argument type in the setter method. Unfortunately it wont work that. It causes `org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException` with message:

```
Invalid property 'providers[google]' of bean class [com.zinvoice.user.service.OAuth2ProvidersService]: Cannot access indexed value in property referenced in indexed property path 'providers[google]'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'providers[google]' of bean class [com.zinvoice.user.service.OAuth2ProvidersService]: Bean property 'providers[google]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

Keep it in mind if you're using Groovy in your Spring Boot application.

Answer (score 18):

Solution for pulling **Map** using **@Value**  from   **application.yml** property coded as **multiline**

> **application.yml**

```
other-prop: just for demo 

my-map-property-name: "{\
         key1: \"ANY String Value here\", \  
         key2: \"any number of items\" , \ 
         key3: \"Note the Last item does not have comma\" \
         }"

other-prop2: just for demo 2
```

Here the value for our map property "my-map-property-name" is stored in **JSON** format inside a **string**  and we have achived multiline using **\** at end of line

> **myJavaClass.java**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

public class myJavaClass {

@Value("#{${my-map-property-name}}") 
private Map<String,String> myMap;

public void someRandomMethod (){
    if(myMap.containsKey("key1")) {
            //todo...
    } }

}
```

**More explanation**

- **\** in yaml it is Used to break string into multiline
- **\"** is escape charater for "(quote) in yaml string
- **{key:value}** JSON in yaml which will be converted to Map by @Value
- **#{ }** it is SpEL expresion and can be used in @Value to convert json int Map or Array / list [Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html)

Tested in a spring boot project

Comment: After looking out for solutions for hours, you saved my day. Stay blessed a good soul..!

Answer (score 13):

In case of direct @Value injection, the most elegant way is writing the key-values as an inline json (use ' and " chars to avoid cumbersome escapings) and parsing it using SPEL:

```
#in yaml file:
my:
  map:
      is: '{ "key1":"val1", 
              "key2":"val2" }'
```

in your @Component or @Bean, :

```
@Component
public class MyClass{
     @Value("#{${my.map.is}}")
     Map<String,String> myYamlMap;
}
```

for a more YAML convenient syntax, you can avoid the json curly braces altogether, directly typing the key value pairs

```
 my:  
   map:  
       is: '"a":"b", "foo":"bar"'
```

and add the missing curly braces directly to your @Value SPEL expression:

```
@Value("#{{${my.map.is}}}")
 Map<String,String> myYamlMap;
```

the value will be resolved from the yaml, the wrapping curlies will be concatenated to it, and finally the SPEL expression will resolve the string as map.

Comment: that's exactly what i need

Comment: the best answer!

Comment: How the same can be done using Spring XML please?

Comment: This worked best for me as well!

Answer (score 4):

```
foo.bars.one.counter=1
foo.bars.one.active=false
foo.bars[two].id=IdOfBarWithKeyTwo

public class Foo {

  private Map<String, Bar> bars = new HashMap<>();

  public Map<String, Bar> getBars() { .... }
}
```

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-Configuration-Binding

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: the link to the wiki is valuable, though. The explanation is at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-Configuration-Binding#nested-property

Answer (score 4):

You can make it even simplier, if you want to avoid extra structures.

```yaml
service:
  mappings:
    key1: value1
    key2: value2
```

```java
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class ServiceConfigurationProperties {

  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "service.mappings")
  public Map<String, String> serviceMappings() {
    return new HashMap<>();
  }

}
```

And then use it as usual, for example with a constructor:

```java
public class Foo {

  private final Map<String, String> serviceMappings;

  public Foo(Map<String, String> serviceMappings) {
    this.serviceMappings = serviceMappings;
  }

}
```

Comment: even easier: You don't need @EnableConfigurationProperties in your case.