# Inject a list of maps from application.yml into service

Tags: groovy, spring-boot, yaml

I am trying to inject a list of maps from my application.yml configuration file into my Spring Boot service. Here is the configuration in application.yml:

```
devoxx:
  cfpApis:
    -
      url: http://cfp.devoxx.be/api/conferences
      youtubeChannelId: UCCBVCTuk6uJrN3iFV_3vurg
    -
      url: http://cfp.devoxx.fr/api/conferences
    -
      url: http://cfp.devoxx.ma/api/conferences
      youtubeChannelId: UC6vfGtsJr5RoBQBcHg24XQw
    -
      url: http://cfp.devoxx.co.uk/api/conferences
    -
      url: http://cfp.devoxx.pl/api/conferences
```

And here is my property in my service:

```
@Value("devoxx.cfpApis")
List<Map<String,String>> cfpApis
```

But there must be something wrong because when I try to run my application, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.util.Map]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

FYI, I'm trying to migrate a Grails 3 project into a vanilla Spring Boot project and this configuration works in Grails 3, but Grails has its own YAML processors.

Comment: I haven't  used `yaml` files so far, but you typically reference a property placeholder using `$` like `@Value("${devoxx.cfpApis}")`. Nonetheless, the [spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-loading-yaml) seems to suggest a somewhat different approach using `@ConfigurationProperties`. Perhaps [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24917194/spring-boot-inject-map-from-application-yml) can be of some help

Comment: This worked great. Thanks. I will add an answer detailing this

Comment: Cheers, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @Morfic's comment, here is how i ended up solving that problem.

I tagged my service class with `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="devoxx")` annotation. And in my service, I now have a property called cfpApis, with the following declaration:

```
List<Map<String,String>> cfpApis
```

And this works great.