# How to get the map values from "yml" file as a Map?

Tags: java, hashmap, annotations, yaml

I have a "details.yml" file, considering all the setting for getting all values from "yml.file" is done. But I am unable to store Map values into
 **"Map"**

```
Here is my "details.yml"  file below


details: 
  company:XYZ
  values:
     name: Manish
     last: Raut
```

And in my class file i am able to get the values of "company" from  yml file using @Value("${company}")

```
@Component
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "details")
public class abcd() {

   @Value("${company}")
   String company;

   @Value("${values}")
   Map<String, String> values =new HashMap<String, String>();
  ...............................

}
```

i am not able to get those values in Mao which i created in  this class, but i am getting values for "Company".

Help me with this?

Comment: Hope below link can help you. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24917194/spring-boot-inject-map-from-application-yml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24917194/spring-boot-inject-map-from-application-yml)

Answer (score 0):

Im the past, I added getter/setter for MAP type and it was work.
Did you try it? (getter/setter for '**values**')

Comment: yes i did try,but getting "null" as value when i m trying to print that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what marshalling framework Spring uses behind the scenes and how it configures it (you could probably find out with some debugging and maybe make it work for your case), but you could always add an extra layer to your application and configure your own.

For instance you could use Jackson with yaml dataformat - https://dzone.com/articles/read-yaml-in-java-with-jackson.

Comment: Thanks for replyng,
i tried that either,not working for me.