# Is it possible to read YAML property into Map using Spring and @Value annotation

Tags: java, spring, yaml, spring-el

What I want to be able to do is:

YAML:

```
features:
    feature1: true
    feature2: false
    feature3: true
```

Code:

```
@Value("${features}")
private Map<String,Boolean> features;
```

I can't figure out what Spring scripting syntax to use to do this (if it's possible at all)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot - inject map from application.yml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24917194/spring-boot-inject-map-from-application-yml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Spring Boot and access custom variables like this:

1. Create a custom class that maps to your custom properties:

   ```
   @Component
   @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="features")
   public class ConstantProperties {
       private String feature1;

       public String getFeature1(){
           return feature1;
       }
       public void setFeature1(String feature1) {
           this.feature1 = feature1;
       }
   }
   ```
2. YAML file will look like this:

   ```
   features:
     feature1: true
     feature2: false
     feature3: true
   ```
3. in your class that you want to access these properties, you can use the following:

   ```
   @Autowire 
   private ConfigurationProperties configurationProperties;
   ```
4. Then to access in that class, use the following syntax:

   ```
   configurationProperties.getFeature1();
   ```
5. Or you can reference the custom property like:

   ```
   "{{features.feature1}}"
   ```