# using @Value to inject a map from yml file to a config property in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-config

I am trying to inject a map like this from yml

```
redisDbIndex:
   key1: 1
   key2: 2
   key3: 3
```

into a
`Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();`

And in my configuration class ( I don't want to use `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="...")` annotation as I already know that approach.

I want to know how to do the same using `@Value("${placeholder}")` annotation. Is is possible? If yes, how? I am just exploring the internals. If anyone can give me a hint that would be great.

I am using spring boot 1.4.3.RELEASE(does it have the feature even?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to inject a Map using the @Value Spring Annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30691949/how-to-inject-a-map-using-the-value-spring-annotation)

Comment: Of course it is possible. Are your indentations correct? Have you got any errors?

Comment: This might be helpful answer you are looking for [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24917194/spring-boot-inject-map-from-application-yml)

Comment: yaa, I am getting an error like this:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'redisDbIndex' in string value "${redisDbIndex}".

Doubts: 
Is the difference between `@Value` and `@ConfigurationProperties` the way they do type-safe injections?
Does `@Value` always consider string values to inject? If i try to insert a list using `@Value` it works but map doesn't. 
Also, is there any standard for the indentation. (I am using a 2 spaces as indentation for the key-value pairs)

Comment: @PospolitaNikita I tried using the "#{${redisDbIndex}}" placeholder but still it does not work. There in the example, they are using properties file syntax. I do doubt that it might not create a difference whether yml or properties file is used but it does not work for me atleast.

Comment: The same problem on Spring Boot 2.4.4