# Spring Boot - inject map from application.yml with variable keys

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

So my application.yml would be something like this:

```
urls:
  login: http://mylogin.url
restInterceptor:
  log:
    fieldsToHide: {'${urls.login}':'password'}
```

And I'd need this in my java code:

```
private Map<String, String> fieldsToHide;
```

First I tried with the `@Value` annotation, like this:

```
@Value("${restInterceptor.log.fieldsToHide}")
private Map<String, String> fieldsToHide;
```

But it fails. It seems that you cannot inject a map from a yaml with the `@Value` annotation, so I tried the solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30540254/7930829).

```
@Service
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "restInterceptor.log")
public class MyClass {

  private Map<String, String> fieldsToHide;
```

And then the map gets injected, but the key's value is `'${urls.login}'` instead of `http://mylogin.url`.

If I configure the map in my yaml the other way round `{'password':'${urls.login}'}`, it gets correctly injected with the property value.

What am I doing wrong? Is this even possible?

Comment: Map have key value pair so in your first case  expression not evaluate '${urls.login}' because it understand as key but in second evaluate

Comment: Yes Dharmendra, I assumed that. But why? And how can I get it evaluated if it's a key? I know it can be done with a properties file, but I'm not able with the yaml. That's my question :)

Comment: have you tried with Environment like @Autowired private Environment env; and call using env.getProperty("fieldsToHide");