# Springboot - injection from application.yml depending method name

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I refered [Spring Boot - inject map from application.yml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24917194/spring-boot-inject-map-from-application-yml) for injecting map from application.yml file

My application.yml snippet  is below

```
easy.app.pairMap:
    test1: 'value1' 
    test2: 'value2'
```

Properties file is like below

```
@Component
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("easy.app")
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class TestProperties {



private Map<String, String> pairMap= new HashMap<String, String>();

public void setPairMap(Map<String, String> pairMap) {
    this.pairMap= pairMap;
}
```

}

But , I found that the value injection happens only when setters and getters are in proper format.ie getPairMap and setPairMap. Not when using getPairs or SetPairs. What is the reason for this behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring takes your property full name `easy.app.pairMap` find `ConfigurationProperties` by prefix `easy.app` and then it try to find setter with name `setPairMap`, it takes property name `pairMap` and "converts" it to `setPairMap`.

If you create method `setPairs` property name should be like `easy.app.pairs`.

Answer (score 1):

To bind to properties by using Spring Boot’s `Binder` utilities (which is what `@ConfigurationProperties` does), you need to have a property in the target bean and you either need to provide a setter or initialize it with a mutable value.

How does Spring can understand that it needs to use `SetPairs` method to set your `pairMap` property? There is convention for naming of getters and setters and you should follow this convention if you want everything to work.