# I can not Inject Map<String, String> from yaml in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, yaml

I have this values in application.yaml

```
import-charge-fields:
  4: billDate
  1001: validUntil
  7: totalAmount
  24: purpose
```

And in service I try inject it:

```
    @Value("${import-charge-fields}")
    private Map<String, String> fields;
```

But I get exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve
>   placeholder 'import-charge-fields' in value "${import-charge-fields}"

I try this:

```
charge:
  hz: 123
  fields:
    4: billDate
    1001: validUntil
    7: totalAmount
    24: purpose
```

and

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "charge")
public class ChargeFields {
   private String hz;
   private Map<String, String> fields;
}
```

and

```
@Value("${charge.hz}")
private String hz;

@Value("${charge.fields}")
private Map<String, String> fields;
```

and it not work

Comment: What about: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24917194/spring-boot-inject-map-from-application-yml ?

Comment: It's exactly as mentioned in the other question, use `@ConfigurationProperties` for complex structures. Considering that this is a duplicate, I voted to close this question.

Comment: Have you tried with `@Resource`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot - inject map from application.yml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24917194/spring-boot-inject-map-from-application-yml)

Answer (score 1):

Numbers aren't valid fieldnames in yaml. Try adding quotes:

```
import-charge-fields:
  "4": billDate
  "1001": validUntil
  "7": totalAmount
  "24": purpose
```

All your java attempts are valid and should be working.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same problem and after a lot of attempts my problem was in the Set Method.

Using @EnableConfigurationProperties You must to implement setFields() method.