# How to inject a map from application.yml into a field in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

This is in reference to this question.

[Spring Boot - inject map from application.yml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24917194/spring-boot-inject-map-from-application-yml)

In that question, they have

```
info:
   build:
      artifact: ${project.artifactId}
      name: ${project.name}
      description: ${project.description}
      version: ${project.version}
```

To map this into their java code, they are suggesting to use `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation. The problem with this annotation is that you have to create a `New Class` and then add this annotation on top of it.

However can I directly get this onto a single field just like how `@Value` annotation does?

Say I need it here like this:

```
// Someannotation or any other lean and clean way to get this
@Someannotation("${info}")
private Map<String, Object> map;
```

The above code should give me a map where key is `build` and value is `some Object with fields like artifact, name etc`(of course if this works, I will create a POJO for this instead of leaving it as normal Object).

Note: `@ConfigurationProperties` does not work on fields which is why I am looking to see if there is a leaner and cleaner way to do this.

P.S. Also I am fine with using `@ConfigurationProperties` and creating a new class, but I just wanted to see if I am `missing out` on a simpler way to do this without having to create a new class altogether.

Comment: Of course I know that, hence the question. I am asking to see if there is another approach `similar to @Value` without having to create a new class and then slap in `@ConfigurationProperties` on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only way I know to do so, is to define the value part in JSON format:

```
app.collection.map.string.to.integer={one:"1", two:"2", three:"3"}
```

then inject with

```
@Value("#{${app.collection.map.string.to.integer}}")
private Map<String, Integer> mapStringToInteger;
```

from https://relentlesscoding.com/2018/09/09/spring-basics-dynamically-inject-values-with-springs-value/ in section **Inject Maps With Spring’s @Value**