# How do I deserialize a series of application.properties to a Map in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have Spring Boot Application, with `application.properties` that look like so

```
com.mycompany.schedule.test=welcome
com.mycompany.schedule.test2=hi there
```

I would like these to be deserialized into a `Map`

I have tried the following, and other variants, but it doesnt seem to work

```
  private Map<String, String> schedules;

  @Value("${com.mycompany.schedule}")
  public void setSchedules(Map<String, String> values) {
    this.schedules = values;
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot - inject map from application.yml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24917194/spring-boot-inject-map-from-application-yml)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but none of those approaches worked, surprisingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1:**

In your configuration class read the application.properties file using @PropertySource annotation as below.

**MyAppConfiguration.java**

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

@Configuration
@PropertySource(name = "customPropertySource", value = "classpath:application.properties")
public class MyAppConfiguration {

}
```

Then in your POJO (or any other spring component), you can Environment class to get the properties.

**MyPojo.java**

```
import java.util.Map;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePropertySource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MyPojo {

    @Autowired
    private ConfigurableEnvironment env;

    private Map<String, Object> schedules;

    @PostConstruct
    public void properties() {
        Object propSourceObj = env.getPropertySources().get("customPropertySource");
        if (propSourceObj instanceof ResourcePropertySource) {
            ResourcePropertySource propSource = (ResourcePropertySource) propSourceObj;
            setSchedules(propSource.getSource());
        }
        System.out.println("Schedules: " + getSchedules());

    }

    public Map<String, Object> getSchedules() {
        return schedules;
    }

    public void setSchedules(Map<String, Object> schedules) {
        this.schedules = schedules;
    }

}
```

Please note that, with this option you are reading the application.properties file twice. If you are ok with it, you can choose option 1. Otherwise, you can choose option 2.

**Option 2:**

**MyAppConfiguration.java**

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class MyAppConfiguration {

}
```

**MyPojo.java**

```
import java.util.Map;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.env.OriginTrackedMapPropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MyPojo {

    @Autowired
    private ConfigurableEnvironment env;

    private Map<String, Object> schedules;

    @PostConstruct
    public void properties() {
        Object propSourceObj = env.getPropertySources().get("applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.properties]");
        if (propSourceObj instanceof OriginTrackedMapPropertySource) {
            OriginTrackedMapPropertySource propSource = (OriginTrackedMapPropertySource) propSourceObj;
            setSchedules(propSource.getSource());
        }
        System.out.println("Schedules: " + getSchedules());

    }

    public Map<String, Object> getSchedules() {
        return schedules;
    }

    public void setSchedules(Map<String, Object> schedules) {
        this.schedules = schedules;
    }

}
```

**Edit:**

Sorry, Earlier I misunderstood your question. If you know the property prefix, then you can use @ConfigurationProperties as shown below. The above options are to read all properties without knowing the property prefix.

**MyAppConfiguration.java**

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class MyAppConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private MyCompanyConfigurationProperties myCompanyConfProps;

    @PostConstruct
    public void testProperteis() {
        System.out.println("My Properties: " + myCompanyConfProps.getSchedule());
    }

}
```

**MyCompanyConfigurationProperties.java**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "com.mycompany")
public class MyCompanyConfigurationProperties {

    private Map<String, String> schedule = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public Map<String, String> getSchedule() {
        return schedule;
    }

    public void setSchedule(Map<String, String> schedule) {
        this.schedule = schedule;
    }

}
```