# Is it possible to have a @Value property defined by asterisk?

Tags: spring, properties

for example:

```
@Value("${a*}")
private Map<String, String> complexMap;
```

and on my `application.yml`:

```
a*:
  "a": "a"
  "b": "b"
  "c": "c"
```

I'm getting `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'a*' in value "${a*}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, @Value is used to bind to one single key. However, if that key has any asterisk, it's still valid & read properly.

**For example**: we can read a property key `test*: hello` using @Value.

```
@Value("${test1*}")
String greet; //hello
```

**Note**: We should use `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation for reading multiple keys, here in your case, to read a `Map<String, String>`, we have to use `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation on a class that binds its fields to bunch of properties. So here, `@Value` is not a correct usage for binding to a `Map`, regardless of whether it has asterisk character or not. [Example For reading a Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24917194/spring-boot-inject-map-from-application-yml)

Even with asterisk it's possible to read `Map<String,String>`

**Example:**

**application.yaml**

```
test:
  comp*:
     a: a
     b: b
```

**MapProperties.java**

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "test")
public class MapProperties {
    
Map<String, String> comp;

    public Map<String, String> getComp() {
        return comp;
    }

    public void setComp(Map<String, String> comp) {
        this.comp = comp;
    }
}
```

Here, comp* property is bound to this comp field in `MapProperties` class.

Now, you can autowire this `MapProperties` class, wherever its required

```
@Autowired
MapProperties mapProperties;
```

You can get the property value by calling its getter method like:

```
mapProperties.getComp()
```

Note: It does not work without this prefix, in our example, **test**. Without some prefix, we have to specify like `@ConfigurationProperties(value= "comp*")`

It throws an **error**:

```
  Configuration property name 'comp*' is not valid:

    Invalid characters: '*'
    Bean: mapProperties
    Reason: Canonical names should be kebab-case ('-' separated), lowercase alpha-numeric characters and must start with a letter
```