# Create Map with List from application YML in Spring Boot using @Value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

I'm trying to create a `Map<Integer,List<Integer>>` variable into Java service.

I have this .yml:

```yaml
my:
  data:
    '{
      1:[1,2,3],
      2:[1,2,3]
    }'
```

And into Java code:

```java
@Value("#{${my.data}}")
protected Map<Integer,List<Integer>> bar;
```

But it fails when I run the project.

Actually the error thrown is something like:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'controller' defined in file ...
```

But it has to be by dependency injection, it fails when create the `@Value` in the `@Service` and the error is propagated. Also I have tested these values

```
my:
  data:
    '{
      1:
      - 1
      - 2,
      2:
      - 1
    }'
```

And it creates a lists with values `-3` and `-1`.

```sh
| key | value |
+-----+-------+
|  1  |  [-3] |
|  2  |  [-1] |
+-----+-------+
```

So the error thrown before has to be due to the definition of the list in the first `yml`.

Also I've tested using `List<Integer>` and `int[]` into the `Map` object.

So, what's the correct syntax to create `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>`? I assumed it was like a JSON object `{ key: [v1, v2] }` but it seems to fails.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you aware that you are giving your data as single string and evaluate it as Spring Expression, whose syntax is nowhere near JSON/YAML? Is this on purpose?

Comment: In general, complex values should be loaded via `@ConfigurationProperties` and it is unclear why you give the hard requirement of doing it via `@Value`. Would you drop that requirement, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24917194/347964) would give you multiple answers for different use-cases.

Comment: I have used this way (created JSON as a string) because an answer in the same link you provide ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65762810/13464279)). If there is another way using `@Value` please tell me. Also use `@Value` instead of `@ConfigurationProperties` is for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

With `@Value` annotation:

1. You should not map (yaml or properties "map") keys to `Integer`, prefer `String`.
2. (Problem) Nesting Lists...

..still, I am quite sure it is possible with (crazy SpEL(l) `@Value`).

[baeldung-article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation#using-value-with-maps)

---

But [Type-safe Configuration Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties) produce nice results quickly:

App.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
public class App {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
  }

  @Bean
  CommandLineRunner runner(@Autowired My bar) {
    return args ->  System.out.println(bar);
  }
}
```

My.java:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("my")
public class My {
    private Map<Integer, List<Integer>> data = new HashMap<>();
    // Getter + Setter!!!
}
```

With this "fixed" yaml:

```
my:
  data: {
    1: [1,2,3],
    2: [1,2,3]
  }
```

Prints:

```
My(data={1=[1, 2, 3], 2=[1, 2, 3]})
```

---

*EDIT*:

The "best", I got with `@Value` so far, is:

```java
@Value("#{${other.data}}") Map<?, ?> other; // raw map!! :-)
```

with this yaml(-like):

```
other:
  data: '{
   1: ''[1,2,3]'',
   2: ''[1,2,3]''
  }'
```

Prints:

```
{1=[1,2,3], 2=[1,2,3]}
```

(jdk:8, maven:3.8.2, spring-boot:2.5.6)

Comment: Thanks, I've tested the link but it fails to create a list... I don't know if it is possible to do it using `@Value`. Also the other way provided works, thanks for the answer but I hope there is a possible way to do it with `@Value`.